# WatckKit (WKinterfaceLabel + DigitalCrow)

Tags: swift, apple, watch

There was a question about WatchKit.
The fact is that in one application I saw that you can select one of two WKInterfaceLabel labels and change the value in it. That is, when you click on the desired label, we can change the value by scrolling the wheel. But I couldn't find a way to make this moment (by clicking on the shortcut to focus the wheel on it). There is a hint in the documentation that this can be done, but they don't explain how to do it.
Maybe someone did it after all, or stumbled upon material on this topic. Even after taking courses on WatchKit, I didn't see the functionality I needed.
I will be glad of any help

Comment: Переведите ваш вопрос на русский язык

Comment: Вы в русском сегменте StackOverFlow написали вопрос на английском языке. Поэтому вероятность ответа обратно пропорциональна лени чтения вопроса.